# Is there a way to use random.choice?

Tags: python-3.x, random

Is there a way to use random.choice in a manner that it will select a random letter from a str a random number of times?

````
    ```def drugname(v,c): 
          con = random.choice(c)
       if con == "q":
          vowel = "u"
       else:
          vowel = random.choice(v)
       return con + vowel
    ```
````

I am trying to figure out how to get random.choice(c) and random.choice(v) to get selected a random number of times.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `random.random()`

```py
vowel_list = []
con_list = []

for i in range(math.floor(random.random()*10)):
    vowel_list.append(random.choice(v))
# Same way for con_list
```